# CameraX not able to capture a photo

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I added the code from

> https://developer.android.com/training/camerax

link
. The preview, permissions and everything else is working just fine, however I am not able to  capture  photo from the button. I declared the button to have a listener and connected the function `takePhoto()`, but it doesn't seem to work, in the past it works fine and I don't know if it's because of the new version of the CameraX feature is using, I don't know but it doesn't seem to be responding correctly. I have the Logcat open and when I press the button, it has the message that is pressed:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@70b5dc2[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@70b5dc2[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

But that's it really, nothing else but that is my issue at the moment, it's a small issue but I believe I miss something to make this simple issue being resolved and I don't know what it causes to do so.  Here is the codes that I will provide below:

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.camerax1"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha08'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha08'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha28'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/captureButton"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Full code in once class MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissions()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        val captureBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.captureButton)
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto()
        }

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }



    private fun takePhoto() {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Processing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        //Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        //Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

        //Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        //Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exception.message}", exception)
                }
            }
        )
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val viewFiner = findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.previewView)
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            //Used to bind the lifecycle of camera to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            //Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFiner.surfaceProvider)
            }

            //Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                //Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                //Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this,
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview
                )
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Use case binding failed: $exc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissions() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissions()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull().let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code lacks binding the ImageCapture.Builder() to the camera Provider which is the prominent reason why it is not capturing Images. You need to bind imageCapture builder , it can be done in the following way . In your startCamera() function , you need to bind imageCapture in the following way :

```
    private fun startCamera() {
        val viewFiner = findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.previewView)
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            //Used to bind the lifecycle of camera to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            //Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFiner.surfaceProvider)
            }

            //set Image Capture Builder
            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            .build()

            //Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                //Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                //Bind use cases to camera
               //Add imageCapture to lifecycle 
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this,
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview,
                    imageCapture
                )
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Use case binding failed: $exc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it actually fixed the problem, the website never said anything of adding the image capture within the Lifecycle. Thank you once again, it fixed the issue.

Comment: Happy it helped . Refer camerax official GitHub for more details on how to use the library.